Approximating expression from Meiser, Vogts book on Stone-Weierstraß with Stirlings formula
I am trying to understand proof of Stone-Weierstraß in Meiser and Dietmar Vogts book "Funktionalanalysis". In one of his lemmas (page 22), he draws the conclusion, which I can't follow:
$$\frac{1}{2n-1} \cdot 2^{-2n+1} \cdot {2n-1 \choose n} \leq C \cdot n^{-3/2},$$ for all n from $\mathbb{N}$, and some $C > 0$.
This upper bound, he claims, can be established with the help of Stirlings formula. Unfortunately, I don't know how to apply that to the left term. Does anyone have an idea, how he did it?
Every hint, warmly welcome!  :-)

The term $2^{-2n+1}$ suggests to me that the Legendre Duplication Formula may be involved, but I have not tried to follow through.

Have you tried to using ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{1}{(n+1)\mathrm{B}(n-k+1, k+1)}$, where the beta function $ \mathrm{B}(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$?

$$\frac{2^{1-2 n}}{2 n-1}\binom{2 n-1}{n}=\frac{\Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi },, \Gamma (n+1)}$$ Now take logarithms, use Stirling approximation and exponentiate again.
